# How do I use C# to pin a marker on a WPF image that can be resized

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an image that is dynamically loaded into a WPF image control. (It's a map.)

When the user sets a coordinate (which is a saved waypoint from a GPS) I want to mark that location on the map from C#.

When the application window is resized, the mark should stay in the correct place on the map.

The map should scale with the window, but not stretch.

I've been digging around for days looking for ways to get this done, but can't get any further than loading the image into the window. The image is in a dockpanel, with some other controls down the left side of the window.

Things I know:
I have the coordinates (longitude and latitude) of the corners of the map. I have the longitude and latitude of the waypoint.

UI XAML:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Grid x:Name="ImageGrid">
        <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" x:Name="MapImage" Source="locimages/woorim.jpg" />
        <Ellipse Name="Marker1" Height="20" Fill="Red" Margin="0,179,152,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20"/>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Code (Not functional, just showing how the lat/long calcs are currently being done.):

```
       if (wayPoint.Longitude < minLong || wayPoint.Longitude > maxLong || wayPoint.Latitude < minLat ||
            wayPoint.Latitude > maxLat)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This point is not in this area. It will not display on this map.");
            return;
        }

        // Map location to image coordinates.
        var newX = (wayPoint.Longitude - minLong)/(maxLong - minLong) * MapImage.Source.Width;
        var newY = (wayPoint.Latitude - minLat) / (maxLat - minLat) * MapImage.Source.Height;
        //Marker1.Margin = ??;
```

Comment: Whats the problem by saving the long/lat of the marker and interpolate it to a new location. `markerlat = markerx / width * (long2 - long1)` and back, `markerx = markerlat / (long2 - long1) * width`. Just do the same for the markery with lat.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I've been trying this. I can place the marker in the correct location, but when I resize the window the marker doesn't stay pinned to the map in the right place.

Comment: When you resize the window, the lat/long of the corners change, so does the x,y of the marker (i guess) You should recalculate it on the resize event of the window/control